# iOS Push Notification with GCM

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM to send remote notifications to iOS application , the notification received in both foreground and background, but in the background the notification doesn't show a banner with sound and badge number on the application icon, what fields i should add and where i should add them

Comment: Did you tried in func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
        fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

Comment: yes, and the notification is received and this method in called, but the problem in , the notification doesn't appear as a banner

Comment: Ok, so there is no problem with notification, check your code of banner, just do 1 thing put local notification at different code level and understand what is wrong and where.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it works great. This is how it works:

- You create app entry at google console.
- Upload development and production certificated in creation wizard.
- You have to upload both and follow the steps in [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start).

Logic works as follows:

- We request device token from apns as usual.
- Then we send that token to gcm service with provided api.
- Then gcm sends back a another token.
- We send that token to app server.
- App server can send notifications using that token.

Cool Features. GCM for iOS has some cool features as:

- Subscribe to notification based on a particular topic.
- Ignore others.
- Send Notification to other devices within the app.

**UPDATE: It's Google with a capital G now.**

If you want to try google sample app.  Just
`pod try Google`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving a remote notification in the background. Likely your `content-available = 1` field is already in the json payload, So send your device a local notification and banner to do everything else you want.

```
let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName //If you want an alert sound.
localNotification.alertBody = "You received notification" //Put your notification message here
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1 //Change what the badge number should be

UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotification)
```

One place to put this code is in a func and call it when you receive the remote notification.